# Spring Boot - Hikari - Exception during pool initialization

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am running my jar file on linux server with java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar vantage.jar and getting following error.

```
DEBUG 65057 --- [main] com.company.vantage.VantageApp            : Running with Spring Boot v2.2.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.3.RELEASE
INFO 65057 --- [main] com.company.vantage.VantageApp            : The following profiles are active: dev,swagger
DEBUG 65057 --- [main] i.m.c.u.i.logging.InternalLoggerFactory  : Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
DEBUG 65057 --- [main] c.a.vantage.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key
DEBUG 65057 --- [main] com.company.vantage.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering CORS filter
INFO 65057 --- [main] com.company.vantage.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
DEBUG 65057 --- [main] com.company.vantage.config.WebConfigurer  : Initialize H2 console
INFO 65057 --- [main] com.company.vantage.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
DEBUG 65057 --- [main] c.a.vantage.config.AsyncConfiguration    : Creating Async Task Executor
DEBUG 65057 --- [main] c.a.v.config.LiquibaseConfiguration      : Configuring Liquibase
ERROR 65057 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at com.anthem.vantage.VantageApp.main(VantageApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Same jar file works fine in my localhost and windows server (temp dev env). But when I run the same jar on linux box (using putty for this) and throwing above error. App is deployed and I can open the front page. But couldn't get in, as, it is not connecting DB and not LDAP server while i was trying to login using ldap authentication. So I tried ping both postgresql server and also ldap server and I got response successfully. But cannot connect through app. Please advise!

Please note this is linux server is newly mounted and not sure if there is any thing that needs to be configured other than javaidk.

my **application-dev.yml** looks like below for data source

```
datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://hostname:15432/vantage
    username: XXXXXXXXXX
    password: pwd!
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    database: postgresql
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.default_schema: filemetadata
      hibernate.search.default.directory_provider: filesystem
      hibernate.search.default.indexBase: ./lucene/indexes
  liquibase:
    # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
    contexts: dev
    default-schema: filemetadata
```

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.